# Setting Kendo Grid Page size to a variable only works when using parseInt(Variable)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm working on a Kendo Grid (jQuery) and have been trying to set the page size to the value of a variable which is acquired from the users preferences settings.

```
dataSource: {
    pageSize: userPageSize
}
```

Setting the page size like this doesn't work and displays the first 20 rows on the first page, but then displays all the remaining results (78 rows) on page 2 and 3 with the last 20 on page 4.


**But** when I use:

```
dataSource: {
    pageSize: parseInt(userPageSize)
}
```

The paging works correctly! I only tried it on a whim when experimenting and can't find any explanation as to why it only works when parsing it, I'd really like to know why.

Comment: The property value expects an integer.

Comment: From your code I guess you're using the `setOptions` method to change the `pageSize` with the object above as the argument. If so, perhaps it's better to use `grid.dataSource.pageSize(parseInt(userPageSize))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pageSize` expects a number as an argument. You get the same strange behavior if you set the `pageSize` to a string right from the start in the options object.

The `userPageSize` value you get from the user is a string and should be parsed as an integer.

You can also see a discussion about this in the Telerik forums [here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-pagesize-dinamically).

Also, the `dataSource.pageSize` method reference from Telerik's documentation [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-pageSize).